# PHP parse syntax error unexpected '<'

Tags: php

I am getting parse syntax error and not sure how to fix this. I would appreciate any help here

```html
 if(isset($selectedUser))
    {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . $selectedUser['first_name'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $selectedUser['last_name'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $selectedUser['email'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $selectedUser['address_city'] . '</td>'; 
        echo '<td>' . $selectedUser['address_state'] . '</td>'; 
        echo '<td>' . $selectedUser['address_country'] . '</td>'; 
echo '<td>'<a href="https://example.com/Coach.php?id=<?php echo $selectedUser['hashword($id, $salt)'] ?>"><input type="button" value="view"/> </a>'<td>'
        echo '</tr>';
        
    }
```

Comment: You have a bunch of `echo` statements, and then `<td><a href="...` Can you seriously not see where the error is??

Comment: @squeamishossifrage i tried echoing that line but it is throwing me same error

Comment: @jon Just look at the syntax highlighting and you already see the error. You know how to concatenate values, why do you do something different for the penultimate line?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
echo '<td>' . $selectedUser['address_country'] . '</td>'; 
<td><a href="https://example.com/Coach.php?id=<?php echo $selectedUser['hashword($id, $salt)'] ?>"><input type="button" value="view"/> </a><td>
echo '</tr>';
```

and add a `?>` and `<?php`.

```
echo '<td>' . $selectedUser['address_country'] . '</td>'; 
?>
<td><a href="https://example.com/Coach.php?id=<?php echo $selectedUser['hashword($id, $salt)'] ?>"><input type="button" value="view"/> </a><td>
<?php
echo '</tr>';
```

Comment: okay it is working thank you so much